# Adding sensors to gazebo - from scratch

Tags: ros, gazebo, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to ROS and gazebo. I have created a world in gazebo and now I wish to add few contact sensors to it. Can someone please tell me how to add a sensor to the world and give a sample xml code if possible ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51773/adding-sensors-to-gazebo---from-scratch/) by [gordon](https://answers.ros.org/users/2999/gordon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2013-01-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can look at the PR2:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/UnderstandingPR2URDFGazeboExtension

Or Gazebo (not sure if this works in previous versions)
http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/sensors/contact

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0